# Calculate Traffic when vnstat service stopped

Tags: networking, statistics

How can I temporarily stop the `vnstat` traffic calculation?

I even stop the service, but the traffic is still calculated!

Answer (score 1):

Not at all.

to cite the first paragraph of [its website](https://humdi.net/vnstat/) (emphasis mine):

> vnStat is a console-based network traffic monitor for Linux and BSD that keeps a log of network traffic for the selected interface(s). **It uses the network interface statistics provided by the kernel as information source.** This means that vnStat won't actually be sniffing any traffic and also ensures light use of system resources regardless of network traffic rate.

That means it is just *displaying* what the network subsystem in your kernel is counting, anyways. You can't stop that.

But you can write your own programs/scripts to do the same that vnstat does, and explicitly save the byte and packet counters before and after "suspension" to subtract the difference that occurred during that time.